# How to fix "No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml" in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am building an android app in `Visual Studio 2015`. It was working well.  I am getting deployment error. When I am cleaning and rebuilding  of the project is successful with no error. However when I try to run the app from Visual studio it tells me an deployment error occurred.

Error in Build Output:

> > No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

I have tried on real device too. It is showing deployment error on device and emulator as well..

Output:
[image: Output Window]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I have a similar issue.

Comment: Try to clean ans rebuild your solution... This error wont cause your app running

Comment: I think the version 4.0.0.0 assembly is .Net Framework, and the version 2.0.5.0 one is .Net Standard. I have the same problem, can't get rid of the warnings, it's because one project uses .Net Standard and another users .Net Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

1. open your project in Visual Studio.
2. Right click on your solution and select  `Manage NuGet Packages...`
3. Select `Consolidate` tab. This will set all your packages in same and right version.

Note 1 : Not sure if there's something similar to this in Xamarin Studio.

---

When I got this error, I removed all my packages, navigate to the project folder delete packages.
Started adding all the packages manually from the beginning.

This resolved the error for me for a while.

Comment: It is blank. I am not working for PCL project. I have just created single android project. In consolidate it shows me blank...